# My collision detection is not working when I rotate my mesh in three.js

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, three.js

I am trying to move a ball mesh through a maze. The maze belongs to a parent object3d. My issue is that when I move the ball I can't detect collision right well because in the rotation, the axis relative to the ball are changing and for some reason I can't control the collisions with the wall. Here is my code:

```
//This function detects collisions
function collisionControl() {
  var colision = false;

  //Checking collisions with the ball
  var originPoint = bola.position.clone();

  //I get the position of the ball relative to the maze(=puzzle)
  var globalPositionPoint = originPoint.applyMatrix4(puzzle.matrix);

  for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < bola.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
    var localVertex = bola.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
    var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(bola.matrix);
    var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(bola.position);

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(globalPositionPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
    var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(collidableMeshList);

    if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
      if (collisionResults[0].object.name == "fin") {
        location.reload();
      }

      // Si encontramos una colision, la bola vuelve a su lugar origen
      colision = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  return colision;
}
```

The function RotacionEje

```
// Function to rotate the ball
function RotacionEje(object, axis, radians) {
  var rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
  rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);
  object.matrix = rotWorldMatrix;
  object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
}
```

So when I press the Up arrow for example it executes, the following function:

```
function moveUp() {
  bola.position.z -= 0.5;
  RotacionEje(bola, ejeX, -0.1);
  camera.translateY(0.5);
  if (collisionControl()) {
    bola.position.set(47.5, 0, 50);
    camera.position.x = 47.5;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 100;
    camera.lookAt(bola.position);
  }
}
```

I have to say that collisions works fine if I don't use the function `RotacionEje`.

What am I doing wrong?